# Reference request concerning PL tangent Stiefel-Whitney classes

Tags: reference-request, pl-manifolds

I am hoping for a reference for the fact that PL manifolds have tangent Stiefel-Whitney classes.

I understand this as follows: they have tangent microbundles, which in turn lead to spherical fibrations, and for spherical fibrations SW classes can be defined using Steenrod operations and the Thom isomorphism. But there may be more elementary ways of looking at it and in any case I prefer not to have to explain it.

I also need the relation $\beta(w_{2j})=w_{2j+1}+w_1\cup w_{2j}$, which is clear in the approach that I mentioned.

Comment: I haven't thought about this much, but for a PL microbundle can't you just re-encode the linear-independence language in terms of matroids, which seems to make sense once you standardize the PL-micro bundle to a genuine plane bundle with a PL structure.  So doesn't it just follow from Kister's 1964 paper?

Comment: To me that sounds more cumbersome than the way I outlined, but these things vary from one person to another. (I,m more familiar with spherical fibrations than with matroids.) Anyway, what I really would like is a reference.

Comment: Halperin and Toledo define SW *homology* classes from smooth triangulations and prove that they are Poincare dual to the usual SW classes. Their definition shold work for PL manifolds, I think. See here: Halperin, Stephen; Toledo, Domingo Stiefel-Whitney homology classes. Ann. of Math. (2) 96 (1972), 511–525.